# Choosing the correct AUC value with RocR package

Tags: r, auc

I have somewhat of an odd question.

I'm currently working on a dataset and after training my model, I'm trying to get the correct AUC and I'm using the RocR package to get that value.

Im using these commands

```
  pred <- predict(model, testData,type='prob')  
  pr=prediction(pred[,2],testData$var)  
  prf <- performance(pr, measure = "tpr", x.measure = "fpr")  

  auc <- performance(pr, measure = "auc")  
  auc <- auc@y.values[[1]]
```

I've noticed that whether I add the `type='prob'` changes the value of my `auc`, meaning that if i predict just the binary output instead of the probabilities, the AUC changes. So my question is which value should I use? I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 1):

What's your model? Note that `predict` is not a ROCR function, ROCR starts from `prediction`. It's your job to specify the model correctly. Of course, what the model generates have a significant impact on you AUC statistics, because you're comparing your prediction against `testData$var`. You'll need to think what exactly you want to predict. ROC is just a statistical tool, it's garbage in and garbage out, so make sure don't give garbage inputs.

What's `testData$var`? It's supposed to be the classified labels. Are they related to your binary or probability prediction (I don't know what model you're using)?

Note that you **don't** choose your AUC statistics, you choose your model that maximize AUC statistics as much as possible.